# jQuery onload function not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to open the popup on click and the click function is working but the popup doesn't load on page load.

```
<button id="popupBtn">Open Popup</button>

<script>
$("#popupBtn").on('click', openPopup);
$("body").on('load', openPopup);

function openPopup() {
   var left = ($(window).width()/2)-(800/2),
   top = ($(window).height()/2)-(300/2),
   pop = window.open('http://www.google.com', "popup", "width=800, height=300, top="+top+", left="+left);
 return false;
}
</script>
```

I also tried like

```
$("#popupBtn").on('click', openPopup);
//$("body").on('load', openPopup);

$( document ).ready(function() {
    openPopup();
});
```

**Edit 1**

Also, how can I get the openPopup auto load on page load with 5 seconds delay? will something like following works?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    openPopup().delay(5000);
});
```

Comment: If you used window in place of "body" then it will works like $(window).on('load', openPopup);.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers' popup blockers won't allow you to open a popup on page load, because it's behavior that's easily abused (and has been, historically). You'll just have to wait until an explicit user action, like the `click` you're already hooking.

> Also, how can I get the openPopup auto load on page load with 5 seconds delay?

You can't, for the same reason: You can't open a popup on most browsers except in *direct* response to a user action (e.g., *during* the handling of the event, not later after [say] a `setTimeout`).

For both of these requirements, you might look at using in-page content rather than popups, with absolutely-positioned elements, etc. Browsers don't prevent your doing those, since they stay in the confines of your page.

Comment: Can I force jQuery to click on that button after 5 seconds or do something like that instead of firing a function on page load?

Comment: @lock: If the click is programmatically-triggered, what kind of popup blocker would it be if it fell for that? Stop trying to find ways around the blocker, which is there for a reason, and instead work within your page.

Answer (score 0):

Below Code will help you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function openPopup() {
                    var left = ($(window).width() / 2) - (800 / 2),
                        top = ($(window).height() / 2) - (300 / 2),
                        pop = setTimeout(
                                    function ()
                                    { window.open('http://www.google.com', "popup", "width=800, height=300, top=" + top + ", left=" + left) }
                                    , 5000);
                    return false;
    }

    $("#popupBtn").on('click', openPopup);
    $(window).on('load', openPopup);
});
```